# How to covert a normal data frame into candlestick dataframe?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, candlestick-chart

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[0]["ToxPi Score"], 
  name="Suffolk",customdata=countriesData[0],hovertemplate=common_template)
)
fig.update_xaxes(
rangeslider_visible=True,
rangeselector=dict(
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(step="all")
    ])
 )
 )

fig.show()
```

[image]

My dataframe looks like this
[image]

I am working on a simple dataset in which i have plotted ToxPi score of a state according to dates.

Now i need to plot this data into candlestick format according to given directions

> Open value: ToxPi value at the first day in a given range of 7 days.
> Close value: ToxPi value at the last (7th) day in a given range of 7
> days.
> High value: The highest ToxPi value in a given range of 7 days.
> Low value: The lowest ToxPi value in a given range of 7 days.

I can't figure out the way how to covert it or separate the data into weekly format

> EDIT

After updating datetime column in df it looks like this
[image]

Please Help
Thanx in advance.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 I think that's kind of harsh – Davion made a reasonable effort to plot the `ToxPi` scores with a range selector before getting stuck on creating a candlestick chart – sometimes there isn't anything to "try" because the answer isn't in the documentation and isn't easily researchable.

Comment: @DerekO While my comment might be harsh it is not possible to provide assistance without some idea as to the data being processed.  A a minimal reproducible set consists of sample input, expected output, actual output, and the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  This question fails to provide this information

Comment: @itprorh66 while I agree that a minimal reproducible example would be helpful here, I would say that Davion has described the specific problem he needs help with in pretty reasonable detail – at least enough for me to understand what's being asked

Comment: @Davion can you provide a sample of your DataFrame? you can copy the output from `countriesData[0].head().to_dict()` and paste it into your question

Comment: @DerekO I have update it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not completely clear in what is meant by a "given range of 7 days", my guess is that a 7 day rolling calculation should be used to calculate open, high, low, and close, and that your data has a grain of 1 day.

I am not sure if your `countriesData[0]` has a datetime column, so we'll use the `alldates` array you passed to `go.Scatter`:

```
df = countriesData[0].copy()
df["date_time"] = alldates
df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_time"])
df = df.set_index("date_time")

## create your features Open, Close, High, Low:
df["Open"] = df["ToxPi Score"].rolling("7D").apply(lambda row: row.iloc[0])
df["Close"] = df["ToxPi Score"].rolling("7D").apply(lambda row: row.iloc[-1])
df["High"] = df["ToxPi Score"].rolling("7D").max()
df["Low"] = df["ToxPi Score"].rolling("7D").max()
```

Then you can use your modified DataFrame to construct a candlestick chart:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(
    x=df.index,
    open=df["Open"],
    high=df["High"],
    low=df["Low"],
    close=df["Close"]
)])
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but i getting an error ||
ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater

Comment: I have also also added datetime column in my df and edited in the question above

Comment: @Davion can you copy and paste the formatted text of the dictionary into the question? a screenshot won't help because I cannot recreate your DataFrame and try to reproduce the error you're getting – thanks

Comment: one possibility is that your datetime column isn't actually in a datetime format. can you try `countriesData[0]["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(countriesData[0]["date_time"])` ? (i've edited my answer)

Comment: It has too many characters thats why i can't send it here.
https://pastebin.com/JSMKHqc0

Comment: also the above code gives me an error ||KeyError: 'date_time' ||

Comment: @Davion did you rerun the lines in the order in the answer? once you've set the newly created `"date_time"` column to be the index, that column no longer exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244488/discussion-between-davion-and-derek-o).